# Which output should be preferred - RS485 OR 4-20ma OR 0-5V OR 0-10V?

Tags: sensors

I am building a Duct Air velocity monitoring system.

The sensor has these four different output types -

1. RS485
2. 4-20ma
3. 0-5V
4. 0-10V

I studied about RS 485 and I think the standard was used for Long cabling with high electromagnetic noise.

My use case will involve long distance cabling as well as high temperature.

Please suggest which output type should be used?

Comment: what is `long distance cabling`?

Comment: i mean the cable from the sensor to PLC will be long since the PLCs are installed at a distance

Comment: what does that mean? ... 1 m, 100 m, 100 km, 10000 km?

Answer (score 1):

All of these will probably work for your particular application. Here are some thoughts on each. Would have made this a comment, but would probably exceed length limits.
RS485: For this application, the bandwidth will surely be sufficient. Your monitoring system will need RS485 capability which is not rare, but is less common than say, options 3 and 4.
4-20 mA: Will have enough bandwidth and noise immunity for this. You'll need to have the current sense hardware in your monitoring system.
0-5 and 0-10V: Will work and you may have free analog inputs in your monitoring system, but you have to make sure you add a filter to take care of EMI induced spikes and perhaps some filtering/smoothing in software as well.

Comment: thanks @kalyanswaroop RS 485 will work if need to read from more sensors..say 15 sensors.. i mean what points helps one how to decide the output type?